# Error 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u25c4' in position 276395: character maps to <undefined> in pandasgui

Tags: python, pandas, unicode, pandasgui

I am trying to work with pandasgui but as sonn as i try to open any Dataframe with pandasgui.show() I get the same UnicodeEncode Error:

UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u25c4' in position 276395: character maps to <undefined>

The code is pretty simple:

```
from pandasgui import show
import seaborn as sns

mpg = sns.load_dataset('mpg')

show(mpg)
```

I tried to use different DataFrames but also got the same Error with this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from pandasgui import show

df = pd.DataFrame(([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]), 
                  columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
show(df)
```

Comment: Looks like the error is not coming from the data, U+25C4 is the `◄` character, maybe worth checking/opening a bug report for `pandasgui`?

Comment: The Problem has been solved with pandasgui v. 0.2.14